# Nexus Player has blank screen after factory reset

Tags: nexus, google-tv

I have an old Nexus Player which I am trying to get working. I ran a factory reset from the UI when I got it up and I was able to get through all the Google TV setup config steps like setting up wifi and enabled location detection. Once that is done I get a blank screen.

I am willing to try flashing the device but I am not sure how. I cannot enable USB debugging because I cannot access the developer options.

I am able to access the Recovery menu where I can wipe data and reinstall the OS but I cannot see a way to install a new img.

I am a noob here. I have tried factory reset a number of times to no avail. I tried to list all devices through adb on my laptop but it does not show up. I really just want to get this thing to work.

What can I do?

Comment: Which model is that device?

Comment: May be you should consider visiting this forum:  https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-player/ROM

Comment: It's an ASUS TV-5001